# `cannot read property X of undefined` on a property that is definitely defined

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm testing my `fromApi` function:

### deal.test.js

```js
// @flow
import Deal from "../src/models/Deal";
import apiProducts from "../__mocks__/api/products";

describe("Deal", () => {
  describe("Deal.fromApi", () => {
    it("takes an api product and returns a Deal", () => {
      const apiDeal = apiProducts[0];
      expect(Deal.fromApi(apiDeal)).toEqual(expectedDeal());
    });
  });
});
```

### Deal.js

```
export default class Deal {
  constructor(obj: Object) {
    console.log("id", obj.id);
    // console.log(obj);

    this.id = obj.id;
    this.name = obj.name;
    this.headline = obj.headline;
    this.fullPrice = obj.fullPrice;
    this.salePrice = obj.salePrice;
    this.photoUrls = obj.photoUrls;
    this.description = obj.description;
    this.address = obj.address;
    this.location = obj.location;
  }

  static fromApi(json: Object): Deal {
    return new Deal(json);
  }
}
```

The test is a long way from passing since the api input object has a lot of properties not yet accounted for in the constructor, but that's not my problem.

The tests are failing on the first line:

```
 ● Deal › Deal.fromApi › takes an api product and returns a Deal

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

      16 | 
      17 |   constructor(obj: Object) {
    > 18 |     console.log("id", obj.id);
         |                           ^
      19 | 
      20 |     // console.log(obj);
      21 |
```

However the console prints the `id` just fine! Also when I was logging the whole object, it was logging the whole object as expected! And this all started before the log statements, when the test would fail on the first line (`this.id = obj.id`), with the same error just pointing to `obj` in a different place.

`obj` is **not** undefined. Why is this happening?

#### Update

As I started actually fleshing out the `fromApi` method, starting with an empty deal (`const deal = new Deal()`) I was getting an actually undefined `obj` argument in my constructor, which is obviously what happens when you don't pass an argument to the constructor.

So I added:

```js
if (!obj) return;
```

at the top of the constructor and now everything works fine.

I *don't* know if that actually "solved" the "original" problem I had, since at that point the console, again, did confirm that `obj` was not undefined.

If someone can wrap their head around that enough to tell me that this question is worth closing since it was due to missing something dumb in the first place, I'm open to that. Or answering it by pointing out the dumb thing I was missing.

Comment: According to JavaScript, `obj` _IS_ undefined. We just need to discover why that's the case. Most likely, because you are using Chrome and the `obj` appears in the console log _later on in the workflow_ than the `obj` is actually being accessed. Verify this by looking for the little blue `i` in a circle next to the console logged `obj`. Use the debugger to set a breakpoint - you'll see `obj` is not defined yet. This is an asynchronous environment issue.

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that demonstrates this?

Comment: @RandyCasburn the tests are just running in the terminal. I actually don't know how to get a breakpoint when doing it this way; and I don't know how to run this Jest test in a browser to get the DevTools. I'd welcome insight on that!

Comment: Are you using and IDE? WebStorm, VS Code, etc.

Comment: Read this: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting

Comment: @VLAZ I've added the actual test code. I could also paste in my mock API response (`import apiProducts from "../__mocks__/api/products"`) but passing in any object with an `id` property would, I imagine, work. Does this qualify for an MRE?